# jest support for mocking javascript 'classes'

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I'm on a project that uses jest as the testing framework for a nodejs server. On one controller (called `ControllerImTesting`), it news up an instance of a helper class (we'll call `ClassIWantToMock` and uses it for the controller. I already have many tests written around `ClassIWantToMock` itself so naturally when I test `ControllerImTesting`, I just want to mock `ClassIWantToMock` out.

It's pretty simple, I've created another js file in `__mocks__` that contains a dumb version of `ClassIWantToMock`. When I new it up in `ControllerImTesting`, I want it to use the dumb version in `__mocks__`.

I've tried lots of configurations at this point but my desperation move is to use setMock like:
`jest.setMock('/path/to/real/class/I/want/to/mock', '/path/to/dumb/version')` How could this fail?

But when running the test, I get `TypeError: ClassIWantToMock is not a constructor`.

I look at my dumb version of `ClassIWantToMock` and change the style from something like `const ClassIWantToMock = (req) => {` to `class ClassIWantToMock {`. I get the same error which kind of makes sense because using the es6 class style is just syntactic sugar.

Just to confirm, in my real controller, I write a line, `console.log(ClassIWantToMock)` **above** the line where it news up the instance. It indeed prints out the `'/path/to/dumb/version'`. It **is** trying to mock it but cannot.

Is this a limitation of Jest? Or am I simply not using it correctly? --> How should this be done?

### UPDATE

`./ClassIWantToMock.js`

```
class ClassIWantToMock {
    constructor(stuff) {
        this.stuff = stuff
    }
    doStuff() {
        console.log('some real stuff')
    }
}
module.exports = ClassIWantToMock
```

`./__mocks__/ClassIWantToMock.js`

```
class ClassIWantToMock {
    constructor(fakeStuff) {
        this.fakeStuff = fakeStuff
    }
    doStuff() {
        console.log('some fake stuff')
    }
}
module.exports = ClassIWantToMock
```

`./ControllerImTesting.js`

```
const ClassIWantToMock = require('./ClassIWantToMock')
class ControllerImTesting {
    static aMethod(req, res, next) {
        const helper = ClassIWantToMock('real stuff')
        helper.doStuff()
        return next()
    }
}
module.exports = ClassIWantToMock
```

`./ControllerImTesting.spec.js`

```
jest.setMock('./ClassIWantToMock', './__mocks__/ClassIWantToMock')
const ControllerImTesting = require('./ControllerImTesting')

describe('basic test', () => {
    test('should work', () => {
        return ControllerImTesting.aMethod({}, {}, () => {}).then(() => {
            // expect console to display 'some fake stuff'
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: i've used sinon for mocking in the past; maybe check that out? not sure what else is out there nowadays.

Comment: *"I get the same error which kind of makes sense because using the es6 class style is just syntactic sugar."* Not quite. Arrow functions cannot be called with `new`. In order to be able to call a function with `new` it needs to be declared as a function declaration/expression or a class. Did you forget to export the class perhaps? Please post a more complete example, it's difficult to help with only bits and pieces.

Comment: @FelixKling added!